# C++ Boost Regex doesn't save capture

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to communicate with a web page,retrieve it's source code and than search and store specific strings( names ) inside an output file.
Here is what I did:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ofstream o("out.txt");
int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("www.lolsummoners.com", "http");
    if(!s)
        cout << "Could not connect to http://www.lolsummoners.com/\n";
    s  << "GET /ladders/eune HTTP/1.1\r\n"
       << "Host: www.lolsummoners.com\r\n"
       << "Accept: */*\r\n"
       << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n" ;
       boost::regex rgx("/leagues/.*>(.+\\s*)</a></td>");
    for(string line; getline(s, line); )
    {
        boost::smatch matches;
        if(regex_search(line, matches, rgx ) )
        {
            o << matches[0] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is,that in my output file,it doesn't save the capture,instead,it saved the whole thing:

```
/leagues/eune/64657">Kenachi</a></td>
```

I only want it to save `"Kenachi"` Without the "

Comment: This has nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches[0]` is the whole matched expression.

The first capture group is in `matches[1]`.